# How to Loop through multiple Date Array and combine values of same Dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Array which outputs the following Strings: `Date(Datetime)`, `Duration(Time)`. There are Multiple same days with different times.

For Example:

```
2019-03-04 00:00:00 |
 01:00:00

2019-03-04 00:00:00 | 
 00:05:00

2019-03-05 00:00:00 | 
 00:30:00

2019-03-05 00:00:00 | 
 00:15:00
```

Now I want to look for the same days and add all the `Time Values` for each day into one `Time String`.

My code looks something like this (simplified):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT date, time_in_minutes FROM user;
$result_sql = $db->query($sql_query);

while($sql_query = $result_sql->fetchrow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) 
    {   
        echo $row_employee_data['date'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row_employee_data['time_in_minutes'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";

    }   
    
/*
Output: 
    2019-03-05 00:00:00

    00:15:00
*/
```

The expected output should be an Multidimensional array which outputs all `Dates` once with the other value being the Duration `Time` added together. For example:

2019-03-04 00:00:00

01:05:00

2019-03-05 00:00:00

00:45:00

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a static array with your provided values.

So, you need to convert it to use it.

We can simply take a multi-dimensional array.

The keys would be dates and the sub arrays should contain respective times.

For taking dates and times from strings, we will use php [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Following is the code:

```
<?php
$dates = [];
$dates[] = '2019-03-04 00:00:00 | 01:00:00';
$dates[] = '2019-03-04 00:00:00 | 00:05:00';
$dates[] = '2019-03-05 00:00:00 | 00:30:00';
$dates[] = '2019-03-05 00:00:00 | 00:15:00';
$output = [];
if (! empty($dates)) {
 foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $temp = explode(' | ', substr($date, 11));
  $output[substr($date, 0, 10)][] = $temp;
 }
}
if (! empty($output)) {
 foreach ($output as $date => $time) {
   echo "<br/>" . $date;
   if (! empty($time)) {
      foreach ($time as $timeVal) {
        if (! empty($timeVal)) {
          foreach ($timeVal as $final) {
           echo "<br/>--" . $final;
              }
            }
      }
    }
    echo "<hr/>";
 }
}
?>
```

**And the Output:**

```
2019-03-04
--00:00:00
--01:00:00
--00:00:00
--00:05:00
2019-03-05
--00:00:00
--00:30:00
--00:00:00
--00:15:00
```

Comment: So what you mean is to combine both arrays (Date and Duration)? Really tried but cant figure out how to use your example ._. EDIT: Maybe my expected output was confusing. I want to have as output an multidimensional array with of just one date with one time (durations combined) for each date. Or do i miss something?